# Equivalent representation of a system of linear (in)equalities

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, game-theory

I am reading about the equivalence between zero-sum games and LPs from Adler's 2012 [paper](https://adler.ieor.berkeley.edu/ilans_pubs/lp_zsg_2012.pdf).
Right after lemma 3, he writes that it is equivalent to represent
$$
(\mathsf{A}) := \{x:Ax=b\} = \{x:Ax\geq b,\;\mathbf{1}^\top Ax\leq \mathbf{1}^\top b\} =: (\mathsf{B})
$$
where $\mathbf{1}=[1,\ldots,1]^\top$.
Why is $(\mathsf{A})=(\mathsf{B})$ true?
It is clear that $(\mathsf{A})\subseteq(\mathsf{B})$, but why do we have $(\mathsf{A})\supseteq(\mathsf{B})$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend's answer:

\begin{align}
Ax\geq b,\;\mathbf{1}^\top Ax\leq \mathbf{1}^\top b \iff Ax-b \geq0,\;\mathbf{1}^\top(Ax-b)\leq0
\end{align}
which means $Ax=b$ since $Ax-b\geq0$ and $\mathbf{1}\geq0$.